# How to change app service from one app service plan to another app service plan with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

Is there any Azure CLI command which does the same as this powershell command?

Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "ResourceName" -Name $webAppName -AppServicePlan $destAppServicePlan

Comment: Using [Az web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest) Azure CLI cmdlets you cannot change the app service plan of one web app to another.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we do not have the Azure CLI Command to change the App Service Plan for an Azure Web App as having the same functionality with Azure PowerShell commands.

I suggest posting this issue as a feature request in the [GitHub-Azure/Azure CLI Repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues) for getting the better resolution.